# React Native - Odd spaces on iPhone X

Tags: react-native

When i try to build my app to simulator running iPhone X there's an odd spaces on top and bottom of the screen as shown in the image. It's supposed to be full screen. Any idea how i can fix this? Thanks in advance.

i am running rn v0.47 and xcode 9.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably you are setting the launch screen as images, try by setting the `LaunchScreen` as a storyboard and be sure to have the `Use Safe Area Layout Guides` active on it.

[image]

[image]

If you don't have a `LaunchScreen.storyboard` you can just create a new one an set it, or create a new empty project and just grab the existing `LaunchScreen.storyboard` and copy/paste it to your current project.

Comment: You're right about that its a launch screen related issue. Already have a laungimage setup and I just fixed this issue earlier realizing i didn't have launch image for iPhone X.

Comment: Hi @Camo Why dont I see the Interface Builder Document section? Do you know where is it? or how to turn it on

Answer (score 4):

Camo's answer is right. The issue is related on splash screen. But i just wanted to share how i fixed my issue since I am not using storyboard for my launchScreen.
So first i created a new launchscreen image with dimensions 1125x2436(portrait) and 2436x1125(landscape) and added it to my launchimage directory.
And then updated the Contents.json file adding this 2 configurations:

```
{
 "orientation" : "portrait",
 "idiom" : "iphone",
 "extent" : "full-screen",
 "minimum-system-version" : "11.0",
 "filename" : "1125x2436.png",
 "subtype" : "2436h",
 "scale" : "3x"
},
{
 "orientation" : "landscape",
 "idiom" : "iphone",
 "extent" : "full-screen",
 "minimum-system-version" : "11.0",
 "filename" : "2436x1125.png",
 "subtype" : "2436h",
 "scale" : "3x"
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, no need for storyboard solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Update your `LaunchImage` assets.

I had an old `LaunchImage` asset that did not include the iPhone X(s) sizes. I tried "refreshing" or "updating" the existing `LaunchImage` asset, but couldn't do that. Instead, I just deleted the existing one and created a new one.

[image]

That fixed the bars on the top and bottom of the actual app *after* the launch screen is done.

My guess is because Apple assumes that if you don't have the proper LaunchImage for the taller iPhone X(s) screens, then your app isn't optimized for the new screen so instead of breaking your app layout, it just uses the limited screen size for compatibility.

If you need a good template for making the updated Launch Images, here's a free Sketch template that I used and it worked great:

https://www.sketchappsources.com/free-source/1122-ios-splash-launcher-template-sketch-freebie-resource.html