# iOS version of React Native app has empty bar at the bottom with the exception of iPhone X series

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, safeareaview

iPhone X and iPhon XS Max are displaying correctly. But iPhone 6s and iPhone 7 Plus have empty bars at the bottom.

I’m using  for iOS React Native app for iPhones.

I had previously had hand-made image files as launch screens before I knew better. And I followed the instruction in the below links to delete the image files and switched to the default LaunchScreen.xib provided by Xcode. I also checked the “Use Safe Are Layout Guide” in the LaunchScreen.xib editing view.

Since the screen size is supposedly handled by Xcode automatically, I thought this would solve the empty bar issue for some iPhone devices. But the problem still persists.

[React Native - Odd spaces on iPhone X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316879/react-native-odd-spaces-on-iphone-x/54965204#54965204)

[Seeing black bars at the top and bottom of the iPhone X Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184859/seeing-black-bars-at-the-top-and-bottom-of-the-iphone-x-simulator/46184998)

I’d like a pointer, please. 
Do I need to check off the “Use Safe Are Layout Guide” for non-iPhone X devices? It didn’t look like it was possible to change settings for each device in the Xcode.